# How to format fantasy currency in Microsoft Excel?

Tags: excel, numbers, format, currency

In the Format Cells dialog of Excel, where you can create custom numbers, how do I format modern American currency to look like fantasy currency? Instead of dollars, dimes, and pennies, I need it to show gold pieces, silver pieces, and copper pieces (gp, sp, cp, respectively), while also excluding any that results in 0.

Some examples of the desired output:

```
$25.85 = 25gp 8sp 5cp
$75.50 - 75gp 5sp
$1,000.00 = 1,000gp
```

Does that make any sense?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do what you want according to your sample data.

```
=TRIM(TEXT(INT(A2),"0 \g\p ")&IF(--RIGHT(TEXT(A2, "0.0")),TEXT(--RIGHT(TEXT(A2, "0.0")),"0 \s\p "),TEXT(,))&IF(--RIGHT(TEXT(A2, "0.00")),TEXT(--RIGHT(TEXT(A2, "0.00")),"0 \c\p "),TEXT(,)))
```

[image]

Actually, that formula can be improved to,

```
=TRIM(TEXT(INT(A2),"0 \g\p ;;;")&TEXT(--RIGHT(TEXT(A2,"0.0")),"0 \s\p ;;;")&TEXT(--RIGHT(TEXT(A2,"0.00")),"0 \c\p ;;;"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I want to format the numbers through the dialogue, not the cells. [Here's a screenshot of what I mean.](http://i.imgur.com/otXgu3g.jpg) I've just about got it on my own, but I can't seem to get the comma to appear in the right place, or have the 0 values not show up.