# How to solve misconversion when formatting fantasy currency in Microsoft Excel?

Tags: excel, formatting, format, numbers, currency

I am trying to set up Excel for my D&D Fantasy Currency.

I want to use Excel to convert integers and decimals to gold (gp), silver (sp), and copper (cp) pieces; e.g. 25.47 = 25gp 4sp 7cp.

---

The conversion is fairly simple, as seen on this conversion table or below.

[image]

1sp = 10cp

1gp = 10sp = 100cp

---

I got this code from an answer that *user4039065* posted on as similar question asked by *[Juddson Ivines](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6431132/juddson-ivines)* - [How to format fantasy currency in Microsoft Excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44228518/how-to-format-fantasy-currency-in-microsoft-excel/44228751#44228751?newreg=d01a2c4c87114bd0957a9ff3637faeca):

`=TRIM(TEXT(INT(J6),"0 \g\p ;;;")&TEXT(--RIGHT(TEXT(J6,"0.0")),"0 \s\p ;;;")&TEXT(--RIGHT(TEXT(J6,"0.00")),"0 \c\p ;;;"))`

---

This code at first glance worked amazingly.

However when it came to converting 0.6 to 6cp, the code messes up and answers as [1cp 6sp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hrFWr.png). For some reason the code is adding 1sp.

A further error occurs at [0.95-0.99](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Sa2n.png), where it drops the 9sp entirely.

I even gridded out from 1cp to over 2gp to check for errors, which you can [see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bf6Kh.png), which is how I caught the 0.95 error.

---

---

Thanks to *user4039065* for their answer and starting code, as well as *[Juddson Ivines](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6431132/juddson-ivines)* for asking the original question.

---

---

Apologies for being new here and my lack of being able to embed my images.

I would really appreciate some help with correcting the format of this code.

Comment: Something like `=ROUNDDOWN(A1,0) & "gp " & ROUNDDOWN(MOD(A1,1)*10,0) & "sp " & ROUNDDOWN(MOD(A1,3)*100,0)-ROUNDDOWN(MOD(A1,3)*10,0)*10 & "cp"` maybe?

Comment: That seems to work. Though it keeps gp and sp in there even if there are 0 of those. 
Can you think of a way to make the text, e.g. gp, appear if there is actually that in there.
As it is now, when I put it in 0.07 it becomes 0gp 0sp 7cp, or 0.97 becomes 0gp 9sp 7cp. 
If you can get it to be 0.07 to 7cp, and 0.97 to 9sp 7cp, and 25.87 to 25gp 8sp 7cp, that would be amazing.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Formula in column C is:

```
=TRIM(IF(B5>=1;INT(B5)&"gp ";"")&IF(B5-INT(B5)>=0,1;MID(B5-INT(B5);3;1)&"sp ";"")&IF(LEN(B5-INT(B5))>3;VALUE(MID(B5-INT(B5);4;2))&"cp";""))
```

You may benefit from several functions to achieve this. The tricky part is to get an IF for each type of coin and also avoid left zeros in the copper coins (that's the VALUE duty)

Probably sometimes you may get weird output due to decimals. You just need to Round the values.

Comment: @user:9199828 I have copied your Formula and keep getting an error that says: "There's a problem with the formula. Not trying to type a formula? When the first character is an equal ('=') or minus ('-') sign, Excel thinks it's a formula: -you type: =1+1, cell shows: 2 To get around this, type an apostrophe (') first: -you type: '=1+1, cell shows: =1+1.     I feel a little miffed because I feel like Excel is condescending to me. Like I know how a formula is made using an =

Comment: Lastly, one thing that isn't showing up right is the cp for some of your cells. For ex. B5, 25.97 shows as 25gp 8sp 70cp, I would like it to say 25gp 8sp 7cp. 7 instead of 70. Similarly in B12 and B13, though this is easily fixed by not having any numbers in the thousandths place. One other mistake is in B9, 2.01 shows as 2gp 9cp though it should be 1cp, not 9cp, 2gp 1cp. Not sure how it messed up that one.  All the other cp bits look good though.

Comment: can you see my comments?

Comment: @AndrewWeaver Yes, but I don't know how to get that output. you'll need to tweak the formula provided but at least is an starting point

Comment: thanks again appreciate the help.